# Is the set of continuous mappings with prescribed boundary correspondence convex?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $Y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be two simply-connected bounded domains. Given a homeomorphic boundary correspondence $g: \partial X \rightarrow \partial Y$, let $F: X \rightarrow Y$ and $G: X \rightarrow Y$ be two continuous maps with a nondegenerate differential in $X$ such that $F \vert_{\partial X} = G \vert_{\partial X} = g$. 
My question is, does this imply that the function $H_t: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ with $H_t(x) \equiv (1 - t) F(x) + t G(x)$ has a nondegenerate differential for all $(x,t) \in X \times [0, 1]$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. $H_t$ need not have a nondegenerate differential; it need not even map into $Y$. As an example, let $X$ and $Y$ both be the closed unit disk in $D^2\subset\mathbb{R}^2$, let $g$ and $F$ be the idintity, and let $G(\vec{x})=R(\pi(1-\|\vec{x}\|^2))\vec{x}$, where $R(\theta)$ is a rotation by an angle $\theta$.

If you require that $X$ and $Y$ be convex, and drop the requirement that the maps have nondegenerate differential, then the space of such mappings will be convex.